# What is the horn torus homeomorphic to?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is the [horn torus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornTorus.html) homeomorphic to some other well known object? In particular, the standard torus can be described by a square with collapsed edges. What about the horn torus?

Comment: The homotopy type is a bouquet of one sphere and one circle.